# Breeze.js query generation with OData filters (multiple predicates)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, odata, breeze

We are working on OData with KnockoutJS and Breeze.JS.. We need to fire a query like

`_odata/Tasks?$filter=(IsIssue eq true) and (Project/Id eq 2 or Project/Id eq 1)`

Since the query string is being generated on the fly (via Knockout Computed). I get it as string. Is there any way to fire filter string in a breeze.js query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but Breeze supports using a raw OData string instead of an EntityQuery object if you want. For example:

```
  var query = "Customers?$filter=startswith(CompanyName, 'A') eq true&$orderby=CompanyName desc&$expand=Orders";
  myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) { ... }
```